Are my power calculations on this MOSFET Power Amplifier accurate?
Thanks to the help of electronics.SE, I've designed my first power amplifier, intended for transmitting CW on 7 MHz.

Before I order parts and build it, I'd request a design review.
One important note: It seems that that, due to MOSFET capacitance, perhaps 20 mA will be sourced from the oscillator, which is presumably more than it can provide.  I'll fix that by adding a BJT emitter follower, once the rest of the circuit looks good.
How much power will be delivered to the load?
How much power will the MOSFETS need to dissipate?
Are there any other gotchas I need to worry about?

Simulation
Simulation shows Rload has a peak power of 3 W.  Does that mean average power is about 2 W (= 3/√2). How e.g. should I compare that to radios that claim 700 mW? It's hard for me to imagine that I'm getting more power than a professionally designed, popular radio while using a smaller power supply and a simpler circuit.  Is all of that power at the signal (and not e.g. a DC carrier)?

Power dissipated by the MOSFETs is harder to understand.  I get:

Should I take the average of the absolute value?  That appears to be about 200 mW, well within the rated maximum of 830 mW.  If I'm correct, I could double or triple the power.  But I'm not sure I'm reading this correctly.
Inductor L2 shows power into the watts.  I assume that's reactive power and is not a problem as long as the current is within limits - the datasheet doesn't list any power max.  Similarly, C2 hits 2.7W, which I assume is okay for the same reason.

Finally, when I look at the MAG(P(Rload))/MAG(P(Vcc)), and take the average by hand (graphically), I get 2!!!, which is impossible, making me think I'm not calculating this properly:


Have you simulated it. I guess not else why would you be asking about power levels and heat dissipation. Please simulate it. It isn't a nice thing to do it's a really important thing to do because you can regard it as a first prototype test.

@Andyaka I had actually simulated it before posting, but couldn't properly interpret the results.   You inspired me, however, to post exactly why I'm struggling to interpret.  Thank you - looking forward to your insight.

That's a decent start. With a Vcc=6V, you might only get 0.6W out to 50 ohms. Raising Vcc to +8V helps boost output power over a watt. Trimming C1 to reject 2nd harmonic might be necessary.  Those BS170 will get warm but shouldn't require a heat sink. Do try to drive their gates with a low impedance - a few parallel HCMOS gates might be an idea.

what is electronics.SE


How much power will be delivered to the load?

You just need to plot the output waveform and the input waveform like this: -

Add some cursors to get the peak-to-peak value (14.794 volts) and work out power manually: -
$$V_{OUT}(RMS) = \dfrac{14.794}{2\times \sqrt2} = 5.23 \text{ volts}$$
$$P_{OUT} = \dfrac{5.23^2}{50} = 547\text{ mW}$$
This is the signal power delivered to the load. There is also a DC power delivered to the load of 0.72 watts. This is because the average voltage at the load is 6 volts hence, \$6^2/50 = \$ 0.72 watts.
Circuit used (in case I made a transcription error): -

Input power is 6x current into the inductor i(L1): -

So I get 1.405 watts taken from the supply.

How much power will the MOSFETS need to dissipate?

1.405 watts minus 0.547 watts minus 0.72 watts = 0.138 watts.
You can get a bit more out if you lower C1 to 330 pF: -

Load signal power is 645 mW now and, input power is 1.582 watts.
My advise when trying to use a simulator is treat it like an oscilloscope before you try doing fancy things. That's all I've done above. And pick a simulator that looks good like micro-cap 12 <-- zip file for installation.

Fascinating.  Thank you.  I tried to figure out why the simulators power calculations (which I double checked by hand) don't agree with Vrms.  I believe I've solved part of the puzzle, which I think deserves its own question.

The MOSFETs will dissipate 0.858 watts total, or 0.429 per transistor, correct? And am I correct that power through the reactive components isn't an issue, as long as the current ratings  are adhered to?

An antenna won't have DC conductivity so, you need to take that into account. Of course if your antenna is a coil then it will have DC conductivity and, as a result, dissipate wasted power. Your question doesn't make this clear hence, that's the potential elephant in the room.

Class-E high efficiency alternative with a small, logic level SOT-23 MOSFET that has lower RDSon compared to the BS170. Output power would be more than enough for your "short" range CW transceiver project.
Worst case is when transmitting into an open antenna port where the transistor would have to dissipate about 350mW. Efficiency goes down if rise/fall time (currently 10ns) of the driving clock goes up. As driver you can use one or maybe two digital gates in parallel.


For theory and design of all types of switchmode amplifiers (incl. class-E) take a look at:
A. Grebennikov and M. J. Franco, Switchmode RF and Microwave Power Amplifiers (3rd Edition), 2021, Academic Press, London.
Tonne Software provides a very nice and easy to use design software for class-E amplifiers:
https://tonnesoftware.com/classedownload.html

I'm studying your circuit to better understand the changes.  You replaced the BS170 MOSFET with one that can handle more current, dissipates less, and has lower input capacitcance.  Nice!  This required raising the inductance of L1 - why?  You also changed the LPF - why? - is that connected?

Classic class-E switching amplifiers with C-shunt are supplied through a current source. The 47uH drain choke transforms the (low impedance) constant voltage source V1 into a (high impedance) constant current source. The shunt-C1 and the series resonant circuit L2/C2 shape the drain voltage so that, for minimum loss, it doesn't overlap with the drain current. For ~0.5W output power the amp needs to see a 28 Ohm load which is accomplished by an L-matching network made up of part of L2 and shunt-C3. For even better harmonic suppression consider adding an additional 3rd order lowpass filter.

How did you determine 28 Ohms?

For (ideal) class-E amp with C-shunt: Rload = (Vdc² /  Pout) * 0.5768


"The shunt-C1 and the series resonant circuit L2/C2 shape the drain voltage so that, for minimum loss, it doesn't overlap with the drain current".  Can you explain that more? I understand that making current out of phase with voltage lowers real power, but how do C1, L2, C2 cause that?

